# Is there a way to make [Table Of Content] plugin while not using revision data?

Tags: plugins, posts, custom-field, post-meta

I have a problem while using TOC plugins 'cause *all of TOC plugins use revision data to recognize header tag.* I'm using my own metadata (custum field) plugin and the data doens't show on the revision page. It means that **the TOC plugins can not recognize my header tag data on the post page.** Any great ideas? 
 *This is one of the TOC plugins and you could see the "get the revision"*

```
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        global $ht_kb_toc_tools, $wp_query;

        if( ! is_singular() )
            return;

        if ( ! isset( $wp_query ) ) {
            return;
        }


        if( is_a($ht_kb_toc_tools, 'HT_KB_TOC_Tools') ){
            if( $ht_kb_toc_tools->ht_block_toc_detected && apply_filters('ht_kb_toc_disable_on_ht_block_toc', true ) ){
                //early exit if ht-block-toc detected
                return;    
            }                
        }

        extract( $args, EXTR_SKIP );

        $instance = wp_parse_args( $instance, $this->defaults );

        //$post = get_post( $wp_query->post->ID );
        $post = get_post();

        if( is_preview() ){
            //get the post revisions
            $post_revisions = ( wp_get_post_revisions( $post ) );

            if ( !empty( $post_revisions ) ) {
                //get the latest revision - this should be the current preview
                $post = current( $post_revisions );
            }
        }

        $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', empty( $instance['title'] ) ? '' : $instance['title'], $instance, $this->id_base );   

        if(is_a($ht_kb_toc_tools, 'HT_KB_TOC_Tools')){

            //extract headings
            $headings = $ht_kb_toc_tools->ht_kb_toc_extract_headings( do_shortcode( $post->post_content ), true ); 

            //don't output widget if no headings are in content
            if(empty($headings))
                return;

            echo $before_widget;

            if ( $title )
                echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;


            ?>
            <nav id="navtoc" role="navigation">

                

            <?php
            //display items
            $ht_kb_toc_tools->ht_kb_display_items();
            ?>

            </nav>

            <?php
        }

        echo $after_widget;

    } // end widget
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem or why revision data is relevant, revisions are stored as separate posts. There's no information about the metadata you're using, it's format, what it is or how it's stored, please edit your question to include the code for this custom metadata. Otherwise there is no one size fits all solution for multiple plugins, the answer will be unique and specific to each TOC plugin ( some TOC plugins may not have a solution ). Depending on what it is that you're storing and how you're storing it, someone can write an answer on wether a filter can be used

Comment: sorry @TomJNowell , my metadata is filled with h2, h3, and p context. I have checked the TOC plugins like "Heroic Table of Contents", "Easy Table of Contents", "Table of Contents Plus" and they search for the h2, h3 string data on post revision page. It is easy for TOC plugins to what the header tags are 'cause <h2><h3><p> are on the surface.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand and you still haven't updated your question with code or example data, please provide the needed information. Note that not all WP sites have revisions turned on, yet these plugins still function, revisions are only kept for a certain amount of time so it doesn't make sense to use them to fetch TOC data, unless you mean something else and have not explained it clearly

Comment: is the problem that you're using a page builder to create your pages but the TOC plugins can't read the page builder content because it's stored in custom fields? TOC plugins use the post content to generate their data, there is no such thing as "revision data", you need to be more specific

Comment: @TomJNowell Yes Yes! That's right. Sorry, I'd want to upload codes but I do not know from where to copy 'cause so many lines...Sorry man

Comment: @TomJNowell I have added the codes from one of TOC plugin (Heroic Table of Contents)

Comment: ok the only reason it's talking about revisions is so the TOC still displays when you preview a post. It has nothing to do with your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reason it's talking about revisions is so the TOC still displays when you preview a post. It's nothing to do with your problem, which is that the TOC plugins are looking at your post content, but you're using page builders that store data in post meta. Unless the TOC plugin was built specifically to work with that page builder it can't see the data.

**Otherwise, there is no general solution to your problem, *it is not possible to write an answer that covers all plugins*.**

You will need to find a specific solution for the combination of specific TOC and page builder plugin that you want to use. There is no generic way that works for all of them.

For example, the answer for Elementor + Heroic table of contents will not be the same as Elementor + Table of contents plus, or beaver builder + heroic.

To find those solutions you will need to ask their support routes or other users in their communities. No one size fits all solution exists.

*Alternatively, switch to a page builder that stores its data in the post content, or provides its own table of contents functionality.*

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm using Heroic Knowledge Base theme(https://herothemes.com/wordpress-knowledge-base) and their TOC plugin(Heroic Table of Contents). I will ask their support. Thanks.